# Can I use resultset.getBoolean in Java to get Tinyint in SQL

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, resultset, tinyint

Is it possible to use the rs.getboolean method to get the value of tinyint(0/1) out of SQL?
like this:

```
while (rs.next()) {
    boolean noUse= rs.getBoolean(1);
}
```

If this does not work, I suppose you have to do something like this:

```
while (rs.next()) {
    boolean noUse= rs.getByte(1)==1;
}
```

Thanks for helping me out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The option 1 should work fine and I have used the same.

```
while (rs.next()) {
boolean noUse= rs.getBoolean(1);
}
```

In mysql, tinyint act as boolean (but save the physical value as 0/1) 
When you perform the above code,

if field value = 0 then ; noUse=false
else if field value= 1 then ; noUse=true